# Browser authentication for AWS SDK for JavaScript using IAM credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I have a simple shell script which issues several commands using awscli and displays information to the screen.  It depends on having correct settings in `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials`.  I want to distribute it to about 10 users who have IAM accounts with limited privileges.  However I don't want to use the shell - I want something cross-platform, easy to use for the users and easy for me to update.  So I decided that I want to create a simple web application in JS instead, using the AWS SDK.

It seems that this use case is specifically supported by AWS, the first bullet point under "Common Use Cases" in [What Is the AWS SDK for JavaScript?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html) is "Build a custom console to AWS services in which you access and combine features across Regions and services to best meet your organizational or project needs" which exactly describes what I want to do.

The problem is that I can't find the relevant documentation on how to perform the user authentication.  All the examples that I was able to find talk about some "Amazon Cognito" service and discuss much more complicated use cases, such as authenticating pools of external users through an external authentication provider and mapping them to IAM roles, which sounds too complicated for what I want to do.  Is there a way to just authenticate the users that I have with their IAM user/password, and authorize them to access the AWS services based on their existing IAM permissions?  Or is using Cognito, creating additional roles, etc. mandatory?

While writing this question I found out another question about AWS Amplify and now I'm even more confused.  Is AWS Amplify what I would want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a web app using the **AWS SDK for JavaScript** that invokes various AWS Services. You do *NOT* need to use AWS Amplify to create a web app.

A Web application that uses the AWS SDK for JavaScript uses creds like any other AWS app. Here is an AWS tutorial that shows how to use the AWS SDK for JavaScript to write a basic web app that invokes the AWS SQS service. It will hopefully point you in the right direction.

[Creating an example messaging application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/messaging-app.html)

This topic covers Prerequisites and other information, such as creating the required AWS resources, you need to know to write a web app using the **AWS SDK for JavaScript**.

Also - the link you referenced was the JavaScript V2 DEV Guide. Its better to use the [AWS JavaScript V3 DEV Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html).